# Publish web project from the build event of another project

Tags: powershell, build, publishing-site

I have a solution that has two projects:
1. web project
2. dll project. At its post event, a powershell runs to move, copy and delete the web project files/folders.

When my solution builds, it starts by building the web project and then the dll project.

I want create a pre-build event at the dll project that publishes the web project, is this possible!? how?
I don't mind using powershell or command prompt.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer here at this link:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1904236/5386235.aspx/1?Publish+web+project+from+the+build+event+of+another+project

SOLUTION:

dll project - test11

web project - WebApplication1

publish folder - F:\11\11

VS 2008

```
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  "F:\Demo\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.sln"  /build Release /project  "F:\Demo\WebApplication1\Test11\Test11.csproj"
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  "F:\Demo\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.sln"  /build Release /project  "F:\Demo\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj"
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe"  "F:\Demo\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj"   /t:ResolveReferences;Compile /t:_CopyWebApplication /p:Configuration=Release /p:WebProjectOutputDir="F:\11\11" /p:OutputPath="F:\11\11\bin"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.